# Gradle sync failed: Gradle sync failed: Timeout waiting to lock cp_init remapped class cache for a2hfc9tvdzsey2shpvt2yk7sb It is currently in use by a

Tags: gradle

I originally wanted to move gradle to the new directory: `/ Volumes / FLASHMEMORY / Android / Gradle`

But since I removed the gradle folder yesterday from the original directory of the original system and re-specified the directory in Android Studio, all the projects could not be compiled, whether it was a new project or an original project.

I always encounter the same error message as follows:

```
Gradle sync failed: Timeout waiting to lock cp_init remapped class cache for a2hfc9tvdzsey2shpvt2yk7sb (/Volumes/FLASHMEMORY/Android/Gradle/caches/3.3/scripts-remapped/asLocalRepo_2l9w7fvtmyueda6rnni9t3t84/a2hfc9tvdzsey2shpvt2yk7sb/cp_init1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e3) It is currently in use by another Gradle instance..
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 3461
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation:
Lock file: /Volumes/FLASHMEMORY/Android/Gradle/caches/3.3/scripts-remapped/asLocalRepo_2l9w7fvtmyueda6rnni9t3t84/a2hfc9tvdzsey2shpvt2yk7sb/cp_init1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e5/tow_init1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e3.lock
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

My Android Studio settings:

```
Project-level settings: Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)
Global Gradle settings-> Service directory path: / Volumes / FLASHMEMORY / Android / Gradle
```

The build.gradle file in the project root directory:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The build.gradle file in th Module directory:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cnblogs.guqiangjs.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Gradle-wrapper.properties File content:

```
DistributionBase = GRADLE_USER_HOME
DistributionPath = wrapper / dists
ZipStoreBase = GRADLE_USER_HOME
ZipStorePath = wrapper / dists
DistributionUrl = https \: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

I tried:

- Delete the locked file.
- Empty the entire / Volumes / FLASHMEMORY / Android / Gradle folder.
- Reinstall Android Stuido.

But the above attempts have ended in failure ...

Please also help! thank!

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Today I try to change the Gradle directory back to the computer's disk, and the problem is solved!

I only modified one content:

```
Android Stuido -> Global Gradle settings -> Service directory path: /Users/MyUserName/Documents/Gradle
```